# Is there a good equivalent of pandas' `apply` for TensorFlow datasets?

Tags: pandas, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

**BACKGROUND**

The use of [`tf.data.Dataset`](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data) is promoted by TensorFlow as the best practice for implementing input pipelines due to their efficient implementation of common operations such as batching, shuffling, as well as their seamless integration with the Keras API.

I may just be lousy at looking up the documentation on the matter, but it seems to me that the major drawback of TensorFlow datasets is that they are quite unwieldy, if not impossible to work with, when trying to implement feature engineering tasks whereby a new column is created via the application of some generic Python function. This is in contrast to pandas' very nifty [`apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) function which can produce new columns from preexisting ones both efficiently (i.e., via vectorization) and in a pythonic manner.

To the best of my understanding, the closest thing to pandas' `apply()` is TensorFlow dataset's [`map()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#map). However, one can't simply use it with arbitrary Python functions since they'd first need to be converted to tensors. This becomes very difficult as one has to have arcane knowledge of the miscellaneous tensor analogues of arbitrary Python functions (e.g., `tf.strings.length()` instead of Python's `len()`). Even when one finds such functions, the idiosyncracies of tensor operations makes them very un-pythonic and prone to obscure dimensionality or type errors.

I've read about TensorFlow's [`py_function`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/py_function) as some sort of wrapper that magically converts Pythonic code into a tensor representation, but judging from the documentation, it became clear to me that this is far from the case.

**QUESTION**

Is TensorFlow's `tf.data` just not mature yet to be able to handle feature engineering in the same way that pandas `apply()` does? If not, what am I missing in my understanding?

**MINIMUM WORKING EXAMPLE**

In the code below, I compare a pandas DataFrame `df` with the equivalent TensorFlow dataset `ds`. My goal is to engineer two extra features, namely

1. adding a suffix to the string feature `my_string`, and
2. counting the number of time a certain letter appears in any given instance of `my_string`.

As you can see for yourself, the first operation works intuitively for both pandas and TensorFlow, but the second only works easily for pandas. Getting it to work with TensorFlow is either extremely complex, or just plain impossible.

```
from collections import Counter
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf

# Create the pandas DataFrame.
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'index': list(range(5)),
     'my_string': ['Alondra', 'Spaanbiuk', 'Ibinth', 'Liefelle', 'Yoanda'], 
     'some_other_column': np.random.rand(5),
     }).set_index('index')
print('Original pandas DataFrame:')
print(df, '\n')

# Create the TensorFlow dataset and define a function to view it 
# as a pandas DataFrame.
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(df.to_dict(orient='list'))
def view_ds(ds):
    data = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(k) for k in ds.take(5)], axis=0)
    # Convert byte strings to Python strings.
    object_cols = data.select_dtypes([object])
    data[object_cols.columns] = object_cols.stack().str.decode('utf-8').unstack()
    print('TensorFlow dataset:')
    print(data, '\n')
view_ds(ds)

#### Add a suffix to `my_string` as `my_string_with_suffix`.
def add_a_suffix(x):
    x['my_string_with_suffix'] = x['my_string']+'.suffix'
    return x

# Apply to the pandas DataFrame.
print('DataFrame with the suffix:')
df = df.apply(add_a_suffix, axis=1)
print(df, '\n')

# Apply to the TensorFlow dataset.
print('TensorFlow dataset with the suffix:')
ds = ds.map(lambda x: add_a_suffix(x))
view_ds(ds)

#### Count they the number of `a`'s in `my_string`:
def count_letters(x, letter='a'):
    counter = Counter(x['my_string'].lower())
    x[f'{letter}_counts'] = counter[letter]
    return x

# Apply to the pandas DataFrame.
print('DataFrame with the letter count:')
df = df.apply(count_letters, axis=1)
print(df, '\n')
    
# Apply to the TensorFlow dataset.
# HOW BUT HOW?!!
# print('TensorFlow dataset with the letter count:')
# ds = ds.apply(lambda x: count_letters(x))
# view_ds(ds)
```

The output is of the above is as follows.

```
Original pandas DataFrame:
       my_string  some_other_column
index                              
0        Alondra           0.209685
1      Spaanbiuk           0.972315
2         Ibinth           0.933700
3       Liefelle           0.186369
4         Yoanda           0.667436 

TensorFlow dataset:
   my_string  some_other_column
0    Alondra           0.209685
1  Spaanbiuk           0.972315
2     Ibinth           0.933700
3   Liefelle           0.186369
4     Yoanda           0.667436 

DataFrame with the suffix:
       my_string  some_other_column my_string_with_suffix
index                                                    
0        Alondra           0.209685        Alondra.suffix
1      Spaanbiuk           0.972315      Spaanbiuk.suffix
2         Ibinth           0.933700         Ibinth.suffix
3       Liefelle           0.186369       Liefelle.suffix
4         Yoanda           0.667436         Yoanda.suffix 

TensorFlow dataset with the suffix:
TensorFlow dataset:
   my_string  some_other_column my_string_with_suffix
0    Alondra           0.209685        Alondra.suffix
1  Spaanbiuk           0.972315      Spaanbiuk.suffix
2     Ibinth           0.933700         Ibinth.suffix
3   Liefelle           0.186369       Liefelle.suffix
4     Yoanda           0.667436         Yoanda.suffix 

DataFrame with the letter count:
       my_string  some_other_column my_string_with_suffix  a_counts
index                                                              
0        Alondra           0.209685        Alondra.suffix         2
1      Spaanbiuk           0.972315      Spaanbiuk.suffix         2
2         Ibinth           0.933700         Ibinth.suffix         0
3       Liefelle           0.186369       Liefelle.suffix         0
4         Yoanda           0.667436         Yoanda.suffix         2
```

Comment: Pandas `apply` is not, and cannot be, vectorised. Python cannot directly read the efficient representation of data that numpy uses, and the only reason its vectorised functions are fast is because they are entirely written in C (or Fortran), keeping the conversion to and from Python objects to a minimum. The second you have to touch Python code in the middle of computation, you lose the speedup: `apply` is pretty much identical to running a loop or a comprehension in Python, and stuffing the result back into numpy. Tensorflow would have the same problem, except worse (as data may be on GPU).

Comment: Your whole post sounds like: "I know pandas, but I don't know TensorFlow, hence pandas is a lot better than TensorFlow". I would suggest to reframe it in a more neutral way. As for your counting "a" function, you should use tf's own functions: `lambda s: tf.math.count_nonzero(tf.strings.bytes_split(tf.strings.lower(s),"")=="a")`. Sure, it's not that easy at the beginning, but you'll get it quickly.

Comment: @Lescurel, thanks for the advice on how to make my biased question more neutral. That TensorFlow syntax looks very pythonic and just as readable as pandas `apply`. I should have done my homework before posting that dumb, lazy question.

Comment: Note that you don't need to do *everything* using datasets. It's perfectly fine to add additional columns etc. using pandas, and *then* create a `tf.data.Dataset` for batching, shuffling etc. I would only bother with doing `map` transformations if it's impractical to do them beforehand for some reason (e.g. data is too large to fit into RAM, the transformations take a lot of space and should only be done per batch, etc.).